# Office Scripts Daily Call Limitation

Tags: power-automate, office-scripts

In [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/testing/platform-limits#:%7E:text=When%20using%20Office%20Scripts%20with,and%20configuration%20in%20Power%20Automate.) it says that when using Office Scripts with Power Automate, you're limited to 200 calls per day and that the limit resets at 12:00AM UTC. If I shared my Power Automate **scheduled** flow with someone and it is now under the "Shared with me" tab, would we now have 400 calls per day? Or does the logic just take the creator of the flows 200 calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's based off the credentials responsible for running the Run Script action. So this would be 200 calls based off the person with the registered connection for the action (probably the creator of the Flow).